# Sliding Panel WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-animation

I have a statusbar with three labels in it. At times the labels have to much text to fit on screen. I'd like to be able to drag and slide the text in each label for the text that doesn't fit on the screen to show up.

Is there a way I can do this in a label?  Or should I create some type of custom sliding panel for this?

If I would have to create a custom panel, could provide me with some direction on how the animate the text's sliding?

Comment: Put the text in the tooltip, so it shows up when someone hovers the mouse over it.  That's standard UI.

Comment: @Will Hi Will, I asked a similar question earlier and I believe it was you that answered there too!  I implemented the standard format, but I'd like to minimize the tooltips in the application and so am attempting to make the sliding panel.  Thanks though.

Comment: The problem with sliding panel is that the Scrollviewer that is the control that gives you the scrollbars needs space so you should find a way to create a template to make the scrollbar very small or you need to create a custom control with the text control and 2 buttons to move the text when too large, but it looks not exactly simple to create.

Comment: @Sabrina_cs My plan was to create a custom panel that would allow you to drag it to the side to slide it.  This would bypass the need for a scroll viewer.

Comment: In that case it could be simpler to put gridsplitters in the grid that contains the panels without any other need to develop controls
You create a Grid in the Statusbar, put the panels inside and put a GridSplitter in a column of the grid between each panel the splitters can be moved to enlarge or shrink the column with the grid inside.

Comment: @Sabrina_cs Thanks this is a really smart way of doing it.  Unfortunately, I'm having some difficulty gettign the gridsplitter to show.  Consider the code below

Answer (score 1):

Ok seeing that GridSplitter are not the controls with most samples around I made a sample on a WPF project:

```
<Window x:Class="ScrollBarsSplitter.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ScrollBarsSplitter"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="640" Width="1024">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="Test the Title" Background="Navy" Foreground="White" Padding="4" FontSize="14" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="Test contents" Background="White" Foreground="Navy" Padding="4" FontSize="14" />
    <StatusBar Grid.Row="2" MinHeight="48" Background="Aquamarine">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>

            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="This is the text of the first panel of the grid" Margin="10 2 10 2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Background="Red" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" MinHeight="48"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="This is the text of the second panel of the grid" Margin="10 2 10 2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <GridSplitter Grid.Column="3" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Red" MinHeight="48"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Text="This is the text of the third panel of the grid" Margin="10 2 10 2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>

    </StatusBar>
</Grid>
```

Here is the window with the statusbar and the splitters, the trick is that you have to set the textblock columns to Auto for the splitters to be able to move and change the size I used some ugly colors to make things visible. In code behind there is nothing, if you want to do something when the splitters are dragged, there is the DragCompleted event that you can handle.